# Rearranging divs with Jquery

Tags: jquery, iteration

I have following html structure (this is just an overview, all divs have content and are properly closed). Each div.views-row contains a views-field-title, views-field-body and views-field-afbeeldingen

```
<div class="view view-toepassingen view-id-toepassingen view-display-id-page view-dom-id-5a6ac8323a7566e5f11218e7b6c49c5c">
    <div class="view-content">
    <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
        <div class="views-field views-field-title">
        <div class="views-field views-field-body">
        <div class="views-field views-field-field-afbeeldingen">
    </div>
    <div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
    <div class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd">
    <div class="views-row views-row-4 views-row-even">
    <div class="views-row views-row-5 views-row-odd">
    <div class="views-row views-row-6 views-row-even views-row-last">
</div>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is rearrange divs to: (effectively move the title and body div inside the 'afbeeldingen' div, and that for each views-row)

```
<div class="view view-toepassingen view-id-toepassingen view-display-id-page view-dom-id-5a6ac8323a7566e5f11218e7b6c49c5c">
    <div class="view-content">
    <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
        <div class="views-field views-field-field-afbeeldingen">
            <div class="views-field views-field-title">
            <div class="views-field views-field-body">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
    <div class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd">
    <div class="views-row views-row-4 views-row-even">
    <div class="views-row views-row-5 views-row-odd">
    <div class="views-row views-row-6 views-row-even views-row-last">
</div>
```

This is my jquery code that is misbehaving. I'm trying to loop through all the 6 view-rows divs.

```
var i = 1;
$('.view-toepassingen > .view-content').children('div').each(function () {
    $('.view-toepassingen > .view-content > .views-field-field-afbeeldingen').prepend($('.view-toepassingen > .view-content > .views-row-'+i +' .views-field-title'));
    $('.view-toepassingen > .view-content > .views-field-field-afbeeldingen').prepend($('.view-toepassingen > .view-content > .views-row-'+i +' .views-field-body'));
    i++;
});
```

Comment: how is your code misbehaving? are you seeing errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might make more sense to do the `each()` over the `afbeeldingen` divs and search for and move the siblings of each one:

```
$(".views-field-field-afbeeldingen").each(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".views-field-title").appendTo(this);
    $(this).siblings(".views-field-body").appendTo(this);
});
```

Also note that all the manual odd, even, first, last classes you have could be implemented more easily with the appropriate [pseudo classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes).

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/De3Vf/).

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `.each` callback, `this` refers to the current `div` item. You can use `$(this).find()` to search through this node's children :

```
$('.view-toepassingen > .view-content').children('div').each(function () {
    var $title = $(this).find('.views-field-title');
    var $body = $(this).find('.views-field-body');

    $(this).find('.views-field-field-afbeeldingen').append($title, $body);
});
```

`.find()` will look into all children (at any depth) of this node, `.children()` will only look into its direct children, etc ...